# Example for an undecidable language L such that L is reducible to its complement and vice versa

Tags: reductions, undecidability

I am searching for an undecidable language $L$, such that $L \leq \Sigma^* \setminus L$ and $\Sigma^* \setminus L \leq L$,
but I am not able to find a concrete language and reduction. 
Is there anything like this?

Comment: Why don't you ask your teacher?

Answer (score 3):

Let $K$ be some undecidable problem, and define
$$
L = \{0x : x \in K \} \cup \{1y : y \notin K \}.
$$
(I'm assuming the alphabet is $\{0,1\}$.)
Then
$$
\overline{L} = \{\epsilon\} \cup \{0x : x \notin K \} \cup \{1y : y \in K \}.
$$
I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: That's what I was going to answer, too.